# Make a div appear in front of another in Material UI when you hover

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How do I make a black transparent div appear in front of a `<MediaCard/>` when I hover over it?

This is what I'm returning using Material UI:

```
    <Box>
  <Typography variant='h3'>Home Page</Typography>
  <Typography sx={{ 'margin': '15px 0' }}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </Typography>
  <Container sx={{ marginTop: '100px' }}>
    <Grid container spacing={6}>
      {cards.map(card => {
        return (
          <Grid item>
            <MediaCard {...card} />
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  </Container>
</Box >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS [`brightness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness()) filter:

```
<CardMedia
  sx={{
    ":hover": {
      filter: "brightness(50%)",
      transition: "all .2s"
    }
  }}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter
- https://caniuse.com/css-filters

Comment: It worked when I put it on Grid

Comment: @prs99 So you want the effect apply to the whole card? Why do you need to wrap in a `Grid`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid item sx={{ ":hover": { filter: "brightness(50%)" }, 
  transition: "all .2s" }}
>
  <MediaCard {...card} />
</Grid>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.